# Sequence of $C_0^\infty$ converging to 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions

Are there nice examples of sequence of functions $f_n\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. infinitely differentiable and vanishing at infinity functions, such that

$$f_n\rightarrow 1 \; \; \; \; \; and \; \; \;\;\; \; f_n'\rightarrow 0?$$

Comment: What about scaled Gaussians, $\exp(-x^2/n)$?

Comment: Or a bit of a generalization of csch2's comment, given $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, infinitely differentiable, vanishing at infinity with $f(0)=1$ and $g : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ monotonically increasing, one has that $f_n(x)=f(\frac{x}{g(n)})$ satisfies your conditions. for example take $f(x)=\exp(-x^2)$ and $g(n)=\sqrt{n}$ to get csch2's example, and another example is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: Great! Thank you!